# Class inheritance in Python dataclasses

Tags: python

Just curious, if we have a base dataclass, and we have 2 subclasses, but one of them literally is just going to use the base dataclass, what do we do about this? Is the best thing to do just use the base dataclass? Can we just put `pass` in the class? Not sure what to do at this point.

Currently I have this:

```
@dataclass
class BaseConfig:
    boot_size: int = 8

@dataclass
class NConfig(BaseConfig):
    aun_pr: float = 0.5


@dataclass
class PConfig(BaseConfig):
    pass
```

We want both to have a `boot_size` as an attribute

As a yaml representation it looks like this:

```
 NConfig:
   boot_size: 8
   aun_pr: 0.5
 PConfig:
   boot_size: 8
```

Comment: `PConfig = BaseConfig` ?

Comment: alternatively, you don't *need* a pass statement. You can also use ellipsis `...` as an alternative, or even a comment block like `"""my dataclass"""`

Comment: yep `PConfig` is essentially `BaseConfig`

Comment: You mean you can do @dataclass
class PConfig(BaseConfig):
    PConfig = BaseConfig

Comment: well, or you don't need to sub class like `class PConfig(BaseConfig)` at all. you can just define an alias, like a statement `PConfig = BaseConfig` (PConfig will still be a class, but essentially the same as BConfig)

Comment: I see, but with the potential of more parameters being added, it's maybe best to just do `...` for now right

Comment: yes, or a comment block should also work

Comment: Conceptually, there is a difference between the (abstract in all but name) `BaseConfig` and the (concrete) subclass `PConfig` that is worth representing tat the type level, even if you never actually add any additional attributes or methods to `PConfig`.

Comment: You should make `PConfig` a subclass of `BaseConfig` with `pass`.

Comment: thanks guys :) so... `...` or `pass`? :D